# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') with gorhom bottom sheet (react native Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using this package, which is compatible with Expo :

https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

I'm doing exactly what is shown in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgeAfiz_j_w

Except that I write :

```
const sheetRef = useRef(null);
```

instead of :

```
const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);
```

Because I am not using typescript.

I get the following error :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString');
```

I have installed the correct dependencies, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing :

```
npm install -D @expo/webpack-config
```

and creating a webpack.config.js with this code :

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(
        {
            ...env,
            babel: { dangerouslyAddModulePathsToTranspile: ['@gorhom'] },
        },
        argv
    );

    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with react-native-reanimated installation. In order to resolve this you would have to put add the plugin in your babel.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/#babel-plugin

Afterwards if you run expo start -c to clear the cache, it should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).